# Regex c++ crashing while initialization

Tags: c++, regex

I'm currently working on finding registry paths match using regex.

I have initalized regex as

```
regex regx("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\\\{0398BFBC-913B-3275-9463-D2BF91B3C80B\\}")
```

and the program throws a `std::tr1::regex_error` exception.

I tried to escape the curly braces using `"\\\\"` but it still didn't work.

Any idea on how to fix it?

I'm on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What is your compiler? OS? What do you mean by "the program crashes" and "it crashes"? What _exactly_ happens? Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: You probably need `"HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\\\\SOFTWARE"` seeing as you need the regular expression to contain `\\` and C++ is removing one level of quoting.

Comment: The literal backslash  pattern is ``"\\\\"``. To escape `{` and `}` use ``"\\"``. Please provide at least a sample string to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit c++ windows 10, Visual Studio 2010 and it says exeption std::tr1::regex_error. This is the first time I'm posting on stack overflow, It would be better if you dont give negative rating for the question! Thank you anyway

Comment: Yes, its working now! Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew I have to escape all the backslashes and the curly braces. So my regex becomes
regex regx("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\\\SOFTWARE\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Uninstall\\\\\\{0398BFBC-913B-3275-9463-D2BF91B3C80B\\}");

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at a C++ string literal (a slightly shorter one that we can read):

```
"A\\B\\C"
```

This, taking account of the literal escaping, is really the string:

```
A\B\C
```

Now you're passing this string to the regex engine. But regex has its own escaping, yet there are no escape sequences `\B` or `\C` (there may be, but there aren't for your actual characters).

Hence the regex is invalid and trying to instantiate it throws an exception.

You will need an extra layer of escaping:

```
"A\\\\B\\\\C"
```

Or use a raw string literal:

```
R"(A\\B\\C)"
```

In other words:

```
regex regx(R"(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\\\{0398BFBC-913B-3275-9463-D2BF91B3C80B\\})")
```

(Yuck!)

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! I'll try to be even more clear in the upcoming questions. Pardon! :)

Comment: I made it even by upvoting!